# Calling Observable having subscribe inside

Tags: angular, observable, subscribe, ecmascript-2016

I am still having some issues with Observables and Subscribers, what I am facing is if I am am calling below Observable method from the component I am not getting Data. it is undefined:

```
login(username: string, password: string): Observable<any> {
       const body =  {
            'Mobile': username,
            'Password': password,
            };
        return this.http.post(`${this.baseURL + this.loginApiRoot}/Login`, body)
            .pipe(map((response: Response) => {
                const jobj = JSON.parse(response.text());
                const loginrequest = jobj['lr'];
                const token = loginrequest['token'];
                const is2auth = loginrequest['authtype'];
                const schoolcode: string[] = jobj['schoolcode'];
                // login successful if there's a jwt token in the response
                if (token && token !== 'Invalid Login' ) {
                    if (token === 'Oops! seems you have not confirmed your email') {
                      return {result: false, message: token};
                    }
                    this.getUserRole(token).subscribe(userRole => {
                      this.userRole = userRole[0];
                      if (this.userRole === 'school' || this.userRole === 'admin') {
                        this.LoginSuccess(token, username, is2auth);
                        // return {result: true, message: token};
                      } else {
                        this.LoginFailed(token, username, is2auth);
                        // return {result: false, message: token};
                      }
                    });
                } else {
                    // return false to indicate failed login
                    this.LoginFailed(token, username, is2auth);
                    return {result: false, message: token};
                }
            }));
    }
```

Calling the method:

```
this.authenticationService.login(this.model.username, this.model.password)
    .subscribe(
      data => {
        // tslint:disable-next-line:prefer-const
        console.log(data);
        let result = data.result;
```

And this console.log is returning data as undefined.

This code from another project is working fine:

```
login(username: string, password: string): Observable<any> {        
       var body =  {
            "Email":username,
            "Password":password,
            }          
        return this.http.post(`${this.loginApiRoot}/Login`, body)
            .map((response: Response) => {
                let jobj = JSON.parse(response.text());
                let token = jobj["token"];
                let is2auth=jobj["authtype"];
                // login successful if there's a jwt token in the response
                if (token && token!="Invalid Login" ) {
                    if (token =="Oops! seems you have not confirmed your email"){
                        return {result:false,message:token};
                    }
                    this.token = token;
                    this.isValidUser = true
                    this.userEmail = username;
                    this.setToken(username, token)
                    this.authType=is2auth;
                    if (is2auth==1)
                    {   
                        this.isLogin=true;
                        this.is2Auth=true;
                        this.router.navigate(['/markets']);
                        return {result:true,message:token};
                    }
                    else if (is2auth>1)
                    {
                       this.isLogin = true;
                       this.is2Auth=false;
                       this.router.navigate(['/verify2auth']);
                       return {result:false,message:token};
                    }
                    else
                    {
                    }
                }

                else {
                    // return false to indicate failed login
                    return {result:false,message:token};
                }
            });
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do all your verification inside your component not your service, just return the observable from your service and do the validation inside the subscribe,

```
 return this.http.post(`${this.baseURL + this.loginApiRoot}/Login`, body)
 .pipe(map((response: Response) => {
    return response;
}));
```

and in component,

```
this.authenticationService.login(this.model.username, this.model.password)
    .subscribe(data => {
    let result = data;
     // do all your validations here
}
```

also you are making another http get method inside your first call to get UserRole, you should separate it as a function after you get the reuslt from the first.

Comment: ok, why the approach from my side is not recommended. Pl not I have not read any documentation. I am just getting my hands dirty.

Comment: you are returning an object instead of observable which you cannot subscribe

Comment: Ok, so if I return observable in any way then is it possible?

Comment: I am not arguing but trying to understand, please see my edited question, that code in another project is working for me.

Comment: are you there   ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to return something based on your requirement at this line

```
if (this.userRole === 'school' || this.userRole === 'admin') {
                        this.LoginSuccess(token, username, is2auth);
                        // return {result: true, message: token};
                      } else {
                        this.LoginFailed(token, username, is2auth);
                        // return {result: false, message: token};
                      }
```